# Translating entire coordinates of array to new origin

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, coordinates, translation

I have a `128-length` (s) array cube with unique values held at each point inside. At the center of this cube is the meat of the data (representing an object), while on the inner borders of the cube, there are mostly zero values.

I need to shift this entire array such that the meat of the data is actually at the origin `(0,0)` instead of at `(s/2, s/2, s/2)`... such that my new coordinate origin is actually at `(-s/2, -s/2, -s/2)`. What is the best way to tackle this problem?

---

**Edit:** Sorry for the lack of data - I'm using a `.mrc` file. This is all to circumvent a plotting issue in mayaVI using its `contour3d` method. Perhaps I should be finding a way to translate my plotted object (with mayaVI) instead of translating my raw data array? But aren't these two technically the same thing?

Comment: What code have you tried so far? Like will need a MCVE https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Where are your 'coordinates' defined?  Don't confuse array indexing with 'coordinates'.  The row/column indices range from 0 to 127; that's a fixed function of the array shape.

Comment: @hpaulj Right, that's what I was worried about.  My first thought was to just rename my indexes to be placed into a x-,y-,z-negative region... such that `(0,0)` became `(-s/2,-s/2)`, but this isn't possible?

Comment: @ZackTarr I've added some more information above, please let me know if you'd still like me to contribute a random data array and set a permanent seed.

Comment: For plotting you can shift coordinates or scales.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My initial question was very misleading - my apologies for the confusion.

I've since solved the problem by translating my local array (data cube) within a global array.

To accomplish this, I needed to first plot my data within a larger array (such as a Mayavi scene, which I did). Then, within this scene, I moved my data (eg. using `actors` in Mayavi) to be centered at the global array's origin.  Pretty simple actually - the point here being that my initial question was flawed; thank you all for the help and advice.